# Sublime Text 3 slow saving to network drive

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I've got a project I'm working on in SharePoint. I've mapped the SharePoint library to my computer and have been working on the files using sublime text 3. However, saving files in sublime is taking some time and cause the entire application to stall for a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `Preferences -> Settings-User` and add this line:

```
"atomic_save": false
```

This should significantly speed up network operations. See my answer [over at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20639093/1426065) for an explanation of what atomic save is. The question I answered shows how many disk/network operations can occur when atomic save is on, as it is by default in Sublime Text 3. ST2 does not have this option, and does not use atomic saving.

Comment: This saved me about 2 hours a week.

Comment: @ZeWaren - glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Its not related to Sublime, it's related to Finder if you're on a Mac and browsing files over SMB, at least in my case. Opening many files in Finder SMB caused high traffic which slows down Sublime. Try switching to AFP instead.